# Android resource compilation failed... Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

i have recently installed Android Studio 4.0.1 on windows to start with app development. The ide was working well and i created some very small apps with it.. but recently the ide throws this error when trying to build the code (shown in image). it throws the same error even for the example "hello world" code that comes inbuilt with the Android Studio.
I tried reinstalling, and even downloading a fresh setup file and installed it, still the error remains.

The error is shown in the screen shot, it shows *Android Resource compilation failed*

[image: Android Studio error]

I am new to this field, please help me in getting rid of this issue

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in your xml file.
`name="De"` is missing the closing Quotation mark.
Be very careful with XML structure since sometimes it's hard to see the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply, this is the default hello world program, it itself is throwing the error

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by the default hello world program?  Have you tried fixing the XML component as I suggested do you still see the issue? All the errors indicate that it is a resource error in xml.

Comment: yes, i tried fixing xml stuff.. still it throws same error.. by the way, the "hello world" program is a default inbuilt example code that starts when we open a new project.. since it is an inbuilt example, it must be robust, but i am getting the same error for that

Comment: According to the screenshot, I can see that error in multiple XML files.
ic_launcher.xml
ic_launcher_background.xml
ic_launcher_foreground.xml

After building now do you still 8 errors, or less?